# reformatting the timestamp in my dataset to have it as datetime

Tags: python, pandas

I want to reformat the timestamp in my dataset to have it as a date + time.

here is my dataset

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYLEA.png]

and I tried this

```
data1 = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\Consumption.xlsx")

data1['Timestamp']= pd.to_datetime(['Timestamp'], unit='s')
```

and I got this error

```
ValueError: non convertible value Timestamp with the unit 's'
```

I also tried not to pass the "unit" in the pd.to_datetime function and it gave an error
The type of time stamp is Object. Please any help.

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 1):

Format of datetimes is not unix time, so raised error. You can split values by `;` and select second lists by `str[1]` and then convert to datetimes:

```
data1['Timestamp']= pd.to_datetime(data1['Timestamp'].str.split(';').str[1])
```

Comment: thanks a lot it works, can u please explain what the problem was?

Comment: @AghyadSkaif - There is problem with datetimes format, for some reason there are some values before datetime like `21928` and some data after like `132` joined by `;`. So for correct parsing need only datetimes and remove this values by `data1['Timestamp'].str.split(';').str[1]`. Then is converting output to `datetime` column

Comment: do u know exactly what the number 21928 means ?

Comment: @AghyadSkaif - Unfortunately not idea.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you check the documentation of the function [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)

If you want to add date-time, you can format like this:

- `format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'`

Comment: there is a photo of my dataset attached to the question

Comment: I am sorry. I did not see. I will edit my answer above.

Comment: no sure not, I had to start after the number 21928 by splitting it, do u have any idea about what the 21928 number is?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
data1['Date'] = pd.DataFrame(data1['Timestamp'], format ='%d/%m/%Y')
```

Comment: I actually want the format to include the time as well, thanks